# obtain result of map-reduce job as stream

Tags: java, hadoop, stream, mapreduce, reduce

Iam writing a map-reduce job in Java I would like to know is it possible to obtain output of the job as stream(may be a output stream) rather a physical output file. My objective is to use the stream for another application.

Comment: stream obtained from map-reduce job is exposed to another application much like how outputstream is exposed in file I/O ..

Comment: For big data processing in a single java thread?

Comment: normally the mapreduce job writes the result in to a output file. My question is rather writing to a file could that be exposed as a stream...

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Custom Output Format and use that write to any stream you want to. Not necessarily a file. See [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#outputformat) tutorial on how to write a Custom Output Format.

Or else you can make use Hadoop Streaming API. Have a look [here](http://www.igvita.com/2009/06/01/easy-map-reduce-with-hadoop-streaming/) for that.

Comment: i would like to know if the output of map-reduce itself is a stream .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this using Apache-Hadoop. It is designed to work in a distributed system and AFAIK providing the way to emit an `output stream` would defy the purpose, as then how system would decide on the *stream* to emit, i.e. of which reducer! You may write to a flat-file/DB/amazon-s3 etc but perhaps you won't get a *stream*.

Comment: so the result of hadoop's map-reduce can only be a file.. I understand that its a distributed system and the result is written to a physical file. Iam exploring on how to get hold of the output stream of the file such that I don't let map-reduce framework to write to a physical file.

Comment: You may even write it directly to a database also. If you don't want the output stream to write to a file, then what exactly you want to do here? And if hadoop would be just expose an output stream then the app  which would consume it must be *connected* to the hadoop system! And if at all anything like this happens, hadoop would need to keep on *streaming* as a server would do to a client *request*! So basically what you are asking for doesn't make sense. Let us know your exact use-case and we may help better.